# Activity layout shown too late

Tags: android, layout, android-activity

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {   
        super.onResume();
        sleepForaWhile();
    }

    protected void sleepForaWhile()
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(10000);

        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When this activity starts, I see a black screen (not the Activity layout). Then, the layout is shown after 10 seconds, but I want the layout to be visible before sleep code.

How can I create this behaviour?

I tried to put the sleep code in `onStart()` function but nothing changed.

Comment: Mind that the code in onResume() is executed after the code in onCreate(), as shown here:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: Instead of sleeping the thread create a timer to block your apps functionality but keep the thread alive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this is just an example, *(I assume you're using `Thread.sleep()` to represent an arbitrary long running task)* you need to move the `Thread.sleep()` method off the UI.

The UI will not return the view until everything on the UI thread is complete. Instead, we can use an AsyncTask

```
public class DoSomethingTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    private OnCompletionListener listener;

    // Pass the interface using this method
    public setOnCompletionListener(OnCompletionListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
       Thread.sleep(10000);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // This will be called after the doInBackground method.
        // This method is called on the UI thread.

        // If an instance has been passed, you can access the 
        // onComplete method
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onComplete();
        }
    }   

    // Create an interface
    public interface OnCompletionListener {
        void onComplete();
    }   
}
```

You can call this from the Activity by writing:

```
DoSomethingTask task = new DoSomethingTask();

task.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    // put the activity methods in here
});

task.execute();`
```

This means that the layout will show, and then in the background your AsyncTask will be running, doing whatever you need it to do. You can, if you wish, then update the layout from the onPostExecute method.

Comment: Yes, right, it represents some other long tasks. Can you show the use of onPostExecute method?

Comment: @1461ts are you doing any network operation or anything that blocks the ui thread, then you require a thread or asynctask otherwise you don't require those. read http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

Comment: I've updated the example for you. Basically, if there's anything you want to write in `onCreate` that needs to wait for the task to finish, you should just move it to `onPostExecute` instead.

Comment: In onPostExecute method, how can i call the activity methods?

Comment: You should create your AsyncTask as an inner class within your activity. Then you can access them as you would normally.

Comment: What if it is an async task class that commonly used by many activities?

Comment: You could use an interface I guess. I've edited the answer again.

Comment: Thank you very much. That structure solved everything.

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
Thread.sleep(10000);
```

which blocks the ui thread. Never block the ui thread. Pls remove `sleep()`.

I don't know why you need a delay. You can use a `Handler` with a delay. Also `onCreate` first then `onResume`.

Comment: I know that code, i added it already for testing. It is just an example code. My goal is execute something after layout is shown.

Comment: @1461ts for that you don't need sleep or a delay. Just do what you want in `onResume`